# How can I loop this sort of slideshow function?

Tags: python, loops

I have this which function which will go through the three images when I click the window, but I can't figure out what to do so that after the last image it will go back to the first one and repeat. I thought I could do a while loop, but instead it just stays the first image.

```
from cImage import *
def drawstuff():
    myImWin = ImageWin('\Python34\images\picture0.gif',300,300)
    a = myImWin.getMouse()
    if a[0] < 300:
        Im = FileImage('\Python34\images\picture0.gif')
        Im.draw(myImWin)
    if a[0] < 300:
        Im = FileImage('\Python34\images\picture1.gif')
        Im.draw(myImWin)
    a = myImWin.getMouse()
    if a[0] < 300:
        Im = FileImage('\Python34\images\picture2.gif')
        Im.draw(myImWin)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you collect the image file names in a list and cycle through the index each time the mouse is clicked inside the image area:

```
slides = ['\Python34\images\picture0.gif',
          '\Python34\images\picture1.gif',
          '\Python34\images\picture2.gif']
n_slides = len(slides)

def drawstuff():
    myImWin = ImageWin('\Python34\images\picture0.gif', 300, 300)
    slide_no = 0
    while True:
        cursor = myImWin.getMouse()
        if cursor[0] < 300:
            Im = FileImage(slides[slide_no])
            Im.draw(myImWin)
            slide_no = (slide_no + 1) % n_slides  # cyclic
        else:
             break
```

Now, this will loop forever until you click outside the image. As the main point of this suggestion is to show you how to cycle through an index I'd like to point out that this "thight" loop is not the way to go. It will consume a lot of CPU cycles even during the time the user does nothing. You will want to think of a way to run the loop event-driven.